# How to set system brightness of the buttons?

Tags: android, settings, system

I cannot find a way to control system (!) brightness of the buttons. I found this:

> public float **buttonBrightness**
>
> This can be used to override the standard behavior of the button and
>   keyboard backlights. A value of less than 0, the default, means to use
>   the standard backlight behavior. 0 to 1 adjusts the brightness from
>   dark to full bright.

Link: [Android API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#buttonBrightness)

Please note "override the standard behavior", this indicates that there is some standard behaviour settings. But I cannot find any API for that.

I would like to execute such code (from my service):

```
previous = get_buttons_brightness();
set_buttons_brightness(0); // off
...
set_buttons_brightness(previous);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try different values for screenBrightness between 0 to 1

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wrote about system-wide brightness, not for my window (I don't have one).

Comment: Ok, If you want to set system wide brightness, you can use the following from an activity Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 200);

Comment: Not screen, buttons -- the one below the screen (usually: back, home, menu).